# Django queryset annotate with datetime calculations

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

I have a model with two datetimes, one for instance creation date, and another for completed date.

```
class Task(models.Model):
...
created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

STATUS = Choices(
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('open', 'Open'),
    ('wip', 'In Progress'),
    ('completed', 'Completed'),
)

datetime_started = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
datetime_wip = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
datetime_completed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
...
```

I'm trying to annotate a queryset to calculate the average time taken to complete the `Task`. I tried using Django's `Avg` and `F` expressions, but to no avail:

```
today = timezone.now()
# We display the data of last 11 months + this month
tzinfo = timezone.get_current_timezone()
start_date = datetime(
    today.year,
    today.month,
    1,
    tzinfo=tzinfo) - relativedelta(months=11)

where = ("date_trunc('month', tasks_task.created AT TIME ZONE '%s')::date"
         % timezone.get_current_timezone_name())

tasks_last_12 = Task.objects.filter(
        created__range=(start_date, today),
    )
    .extra({'month': where})
    .values('month')
    .order_by('month')
    .annotate(
        cmpl_time=Avg(F('datetime_completed') - F('datetime_started')),
    )
    .values_list('month', 'cmpl_time')

...

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Then, I tried to use a combination of `Sum` and `Count` to calculate the average, but that didn't work either:

```
tasks_last_12 = Task.objects.filter(
        created__range=(start_date, today),
    )
    .extra({'month': where})
    .values('month')
    .order_by('month')
    .annotate(
        cmpl_time=Sum(
            (F('datetime_completed') - F('datetime_started')) / Count('datetime_completed')

        )
    )
    .values_list('month', 'cmpl_time'))

...

FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field
```

How can I go about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Postgres, then you can use the [django-pg-utils](https://github.com/hypertrack/django-pg-utils) package for this. Cast the duration field into seconds and then take the average

```
from pg_utils import Seconds
from django.db.models import Avg

Task.objects.annotate(cmpl_time=Avg(Seconds(F('datetime_completed') - F('datetime_started'))))
```

Comment: what if use mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but:

1. You may have to subtract the dates in python, rather than in the ORM: `date1 - date2` will give you a `timedelta` object. Sum those and divide by the `len` of the list.
2. Try setting the output_field argument to your call on `Sum(..., output_field=DateField())`
3. Your calculation for cmpl_time should call `Sum` before dividing by `Count` in order to calculate the average.